# usage of bidirectional mosfet

Tags: mosfet

In the schematic of arduino due there's a mosfet between of "USBVCCU2" and 5V line.
http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-Due-schematic.pdf
I refered to T2 (FDN340P) P-Channel Mosfet. What's the usage of that mosfet?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case when the device is self-powered, as opposed to being powered from USB bus.  In such case, the T1 prevents the device (Arduino board in this case) from back-powering the USB host.

[image]

The title says "bidirectional MOSFET", but I wouldn't call is bidirectional.  It's a regular P-channel MOSFET.

Comment: it isn't "bidirectional" it is in this circuit as it shows

Answer (score 1):

It prevents the board both from backpowering an unpowered USB connection and from providing power to the USB connection of the USB communication chip (thereby rendering USB communications inactive).

Comment: Why has to be there? it doesn't work without mosfet?

Comment: 2 reasons: 1) to prevent backpowering, which USB devices are not supposed to do, and 2) to reduce EMI from the board since the USB functionality of the USB communication chip will be inactive.